# NSString like '\uf003" replace '\' with some other string in in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i need to send smiley to other user through iphone app ,so i need to replace \ string with some unique string in obj c.

Comment: you want to smiley(:)) insted of \ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encoding` of `NSString` and when need to `use` or `show` string `decode` it.

Refer [base64-encoding](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

here if your string is @"\ud83d\ude04" then it is give error "Invalid Character" so put this ' special character and then use it ..

```
     NSString *str = @"\'ud83d\'ude04";//// here if your string is @"\ud83d\ude04" then it is give error "Invalid Character" so put this ' special character and then use it
     NSString *smileWithString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@":)"]; 
                                 [smileWithString retain];
    NSLog(@"\n\n SmileString %@ Str %@",smileWithString);
```

**Update:**

Here’s how to convert `NSString` to `NSData` – it’s really simple:

```
NSString *myString = @"Some String";
NSData *myData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And what about the reverse conversion, i.e. how to convert `NSData` to `NSString`? Here’s one quick way:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s",[myData length], [myData bytes]];
```

Comment: NSString *str = @"\rewwww";
        
        NSString *smileWithString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"
                                                                 withString:@":)"];
        [smileWithString retain];   i tried this but it give 3 errors ...

Comment: you cant use directy `"\"` in above code. It will always give errors

Comment: @RahulPatel yes mate i know but see my updated code .. i just edit for megha requirement.. see now

Comment: She has string like `"\ud83d\ude04"`. not like `"\r"`.

Comment: @RahulPatel but in comment above just see which code she send me so i just edit that code and after testing i post this answer mate see 1st comment under my answer

Comment: @paras thanks this works ,but my string in not @"\rewwww",it is just an example.my string comes "\ud83d\ude04" ,in which this code does not work,....can u help me to convert \ in my string \ud83d\ude04....

Comment: @megha which string you want from "\ud83d\ude04" this string??

Comment: @RahulPatel if you know and understand that why i post this answer then can you upvote the answer please??

Comment: @ParasJoshi yes i need "\ud83d\ude04" string to replace \ with some unique string.

Comment: @ParasJoshi i downvoted it because she wrote in her main subject what she wants to replace and you give other answer buddy

Comment: @RahulPatel ok mate i write this answer with requirement of megha which she post in comment so as you wish mate.. and also this works but she wants to another so ..

Comment: @megha here if i write string with this NSString *str = @"\'ud83d\'ude04"; insted of NSString *str = @"\ud83d\ude04"; then its work fine but if i use your @"\ud83d\ude04" string then it is give me error so please post full string.. its give error invalid character..

Comment: @paras same error here also..  NSData *newdata=[txtreplyfield.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
      
        
        NSString *strTextMsg =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
In textfield i pass smily from emoji keyboard..i want to use these smilies in my chat app.but strings like "\uf003"  when decoded gaves some other string ,So i need to replace my \ string in order to get proper decoding of my smiley....

Comment: @megha but which type of string you entered in textfield? and why you convert it in NSData and also in NSString??

Comment: @megha see how to convert NData to NSString and NSString into NSData and then try to solve this problem...

Comment: @RahulPatel see my Edited Answer and tell me something if anything required .. and also give the answer if you know anything..

Comment: @ParasJoshi : its just perfect for `\'`. but we have to find answer for only `"\"` replacement. so we have to think on it. otherwise its perfect answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your looking for `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` that should do the trick.

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@"uniqueString"];
```

Comment: please explain, I've used that method hundreds of times before and I never had any trouble with it?

Comment: my string is @"\ud83d\ude04" i have to replace \ with some other string..i have tried NSCharcterSet,NSScanner,StringByreplaceOccurrenceOfString...but no sucess......

Comment: @rahul how i convert my string \ud83d\ude04 into '\'ud83d'\'ude04 format for replacing the \ string??

Comment: It does not work because the "\uXXXX" is not really in the string, it's just a convention for representing wide characters to the compiler.